# Fitting logistic regression model to self-grouped data

Tags: r

I initally had a data set of ungrouped data which I converted in to catergorical(on the column Occupation) i would now like to fit a logistic regression model to the data i created with "success's" being denoted by the number of people who died in each Occupation catergory.

**DATA USED AND GROUPING OF DATA**

My initial data set before any grouping looks like this:

```
 Occupation Education Age Died
1  household Secondary  39   no
2    farming   primary  83  yes
3    farming   primary  60  yes
4    farming   primary  73  yes
5    farming Secondary  51   no
6    farming iliterate  62  yes
```

Then i grouped data using:

```
occu %>% group_by(Occupation, Died) %>% count()##use this to group on the occupation of the suicide victimrs
```

which leads to the following output:

```
Occupation       Died      n
   <fct>            <fct> <int>
 1 business/service no       12
 2 business/service yes       9
 3 farming          no      939
 4 farming          yes    1093
 5 household        no      154
 6 household        yes      94
 7 others           yes       3
 8 others/unknown   no      146
 9 others/unknown   yes      10
10 professional     no       11
11 professional     yes      26
12 retiree          no        3
13 student          no       27
14 student          yes       8
15 unemployed       no       23
16 unemployed       yes       7
17 worker           yes       6
```

i grouped the above into a table so i use the values using the following:

```
dt %>% group_by(Occupation) %>% 
  mutate(total=sum(n), prop=n/total)
```

which gives output:

```
 ccupation       Died      n total   prop
   <fct>            <fct> <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 business/service no       12    21 0.571 
 2 business/service yes       9    21 0.429 
 3 farming          no      939  2032 0.462 
 4 farming          yes    1093  2032 0.538 
 5 household        no      154   248 0.621 
 6 household        yes      94   248 0.379 
 7 others           yes       3     3 1     
 8 others/unknown   no      146   156 0.936 
 9 others/unknown   yes      10   156 0.0641
```

**Question**

My question is no how can i run a logistic regression model to this grouped data with Died = yes being a success and = no being a failure using all three of the predictors in the original model (Education, Age, Grouped Occupation).

Comment: From a programming point of view, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836916/how-can-i-apply-grouped-data-to-grouped-models-using-broom-and-dplyr). Statistically speaking I don't think your method is correct i.e. doing count then total and prop

Comment: Thank you for the input, will check out the link, i was concerned about the method, would you have any suggestion on trying to tackle this ?

Comment: I would directly fit LR for `Died` as a function of `Age`, just pay attention for `others` as it doesn't have `no` category so you may need to combine it with `others/unknown`. If you have enough sample size for `Education` in each category then you may consider adding `Education` to the model.

Comment: Finally, make sure Died is a factor type and `no` is the reference level or transfer it to 0=Died and 1=yes